# Prove every subspace of finite dim V is the intersection of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

A hyperplane in V is defined as the kernel of a linear functional. Show that every subspace of V is the intersection of hyperplanes.

Please can someone offer insight into how I prove this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Let $W \subset V$ be a subspace. Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be a basis for $W$, and extend it to a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$.

Comment: How do I express that as intersection though? Thank you

Comment: Another hint: let $f_i: V \to F$ be the linear functional defined by $v_i \mapsto 1$ and $v_j \mapsto 0$ for $j \neq i$.

Comment: @Dustan: Thank you for pointing out the flaw in my putative answer! Now that I'm thinking along the correct lines, it seems to me that your hints (together) comprise a fine answer. Convert it?

Comment: Alright. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $W \subset V$ be a subspace, let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be a basis for $W$, and extend it to a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$.

For each $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, let $f_i: V \to F$ be the linear functional defined by $v_i \mapsto 1$ and $v_j \mapsto 0$ for $j \neq i$. Use these functions to express $W$ as an intersection of hyperplanes.

Answer (score 0):

One can makeup a little bit the notation considering an orthonormal basis $\{v_{1},\dots, v_{k}\}$ of $W$; then extend this to an orthonormal basis
$\{v_{1}, \dots, v_{k}, \dots v_{n}\}$ of $V$; and consider the $n-k$ hyperplanes
$$
H_{i} = \{x \in V : \langle x, v_{i}\rangle = 0\}, \quad \text{for} \quad k+1\leq i \leq n.
$$
Let us write $x = \langle x, v_{1} \rangle + \cdots +\langle x, v_{k}\rangle
+ \cdots + \langle x, v_{n}\rangle \in V$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
x \in W &\iff \langle x, v_{i}\rangle = 0 \quad \text{for} \quad k+1 \leq i \leq n \\
&\iff x \in H_{i} \quad \text{for} \quad k + 1\leq i \leq n\\
&\iff x \in \bigcap_{i= k+1}^{n}H_{i}.
\end{align*}
$$