# Let $N$ be a $p$-dimensional subspace of $E^*$ and $G := N^\perp$. Then $\operatorname{codim} G = p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Two [Hamel bases](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition) of the same vector space have [the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/proof-that-two-bases-of-a-vector-space-have-the-same-cardinality-in-the-infinite), so we define the dimension of a vector space as the [cardinality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) of one of its [Hamel basis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition). I'm trying to prove that

> Let $N$ be a $p$-dimensional subspace of $E^*$ and
> $$
> G := N^\perp := \{x \in E : \langle f, x \rangle =0 \text{ for all } f \in N\}.
> $$
> Then $p = \operatorname{codim} G := \dim(E/G)$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $\{f_1, \ldots, f_p\}$ be a basis of $N$. We consider the function
$$
\Phi:E \to \mathbb R^p, x \mapsto (\langle f_1, x \rangle, \ldots, \langle f_p, x \rangle).
$$

Then $\Phi$ is a continuous linear map with $\ker \Phi = G$. Let's prove that $\Phi$ is surjective. Suppose not; then there is $\alpha =(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_p) \in \mathbb R^p \setminus \operatorname{im} \Phi$. Because $\dim (\operatorname{im} \Phi) <\infty$, we get $\operatorname{im} \Phi$ is closed. By Hahn–Banach theorem, there are real numbers $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$ and a vector $\beta =(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_p) \in \mathbb R^p \setminus \{0\}$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i \langle f_i, x \rangle < \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i \alpha_i,
$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $\Phi$ is surjective. By [first isomorphism theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(groups)) for groups,
$$
\operatorname{im} \Phi \cong E / \ker \Phi.
$$

It follows that $\mathbb R^p \cong E/G$. The claim then follows.

Comment: You should probably clarify what exactly is the contradiction: the reason is because $\mathrm{im}\,\Phi$ is a linear subspace, so applying the Hahn-Banach theorem actually tells you $\sum_i \beta_i \langle f_i, x\rangle = 0$ for all $x \in E$, where $\beta_i$ are scalars which are not all zero. But then this means $\sum_i \beta_i f_i = 0$, contradicting the fact that $f_i$ is a basis.

Comment: Also, you don’t really need to say $\Phi$ is continuous, or really use Hahn-Banach. You’re working in finite dimensions after all.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented 4 hours ago by @DavidGao](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4703294/timeline), you should probably clarify what exactly is the contradiction, and you don’t really need to say $Φ$ is continuous, or really use Hahn-Banach.

Here is an improved version of your proof, valid for a vector space over an arbitrary field of scalars $K$:

Let $(f_1,\dots,f_p)$ be a basis of $N$. We consider the function
$$\Phi:E\to K^p,\;x\mapsto\left(f_1(x),\dots,f_p(x)\right).$$
By the [first isomorphism theorem for modules](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(modules)), the two vector spaces $E/G=E/\ker\Phi$ and $\operatorname{im}\Phi$ are isomorphic. Let us prove by contradiction that the latter is of dimension $p$. If it were not, it would be a strict subspace of $K^p$, hence [contained in some hyperplane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534164) $H$, defined by an equation $\beta_1y_1+\dots+\beta_py_p=0$ for some non-zero $(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_p)\in K^p$. But $\operatorname{im}\Phi\subseteq H$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^p\beta_if_i=0$, which is impossible since $f_1,\dots,f_p$ are linearly independent.